# C# How to break when private field is changed?

Tags: c#, debugging, field, private, breakpoints

I've following code:

```
private int a;

public int A
{
   get{return a;}
   set{a = value;}
}
```

My problem is that the value of field 'a' is changed runtime and I'm trying to debug who is changing the value of it. There is no references to field 'a' besides the setter of A. I'm debugging with Visual Studio 2015 and have a breakpoint where A is set, but the breakpoint is never hit.

Because of this I think it's possible that someone is setting value of 'a' via reflection. Is there any options to set the app to break whenever the value of private field 'a' is changed?

Comment: Are you running the debug build? I could imagine the release version optimising out the trivial `set`.

Comment: I got the issue resolved but the solution was not related to the original question. I had the containing class implemented with Singleton pattern but due to a bug in the code there was multiple instances of my singleton class.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try a different approach. If you're sure that nothing else is setting a, and you think that someone might be setting it via reflection, change it's name. Make it "_a" instead. That'll foil the reflection, and you can be sure that the value is only set by your property again. At that point, when the app crashes (assuming someone is actually using reflection), then you'll see it in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

There are other possibilties like like managed heap corruption which can also exhibit the same symptom. If your application crashes with an ExecutionEngineException then you need to search for unsafe und unmanaged code which can corrupt your managed heap.

Windbg can be of some help which supports the [ba (break on access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command. There you can define a breakpoint which is hit when when you write to a specific memory location. This is not as easy as it may sound because the managed heap is frequenctly compacted which will cause your object to move around quite often. If you can pin the object somehow then this might be a viable debugging approach.

Visual Studio supports this facility. It is called [Data Breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but this is only supported for unmanaged code for reasons outlined above.